# Loading a texture in GLM

Tags: c++, opengl, model, textures

hey im using GLM(made by nate robins) with SFML and opengl on mingw32 with the IDE as CodeBlocks(windows)

when loading my texture with the GLM from: http://www.3dcodingtutorial.com/Working-with-3D-models/Getting-GLM.html

hey i managed to get rid of the color problem by changing up my code to better load the textures, but now im not able to get the texture to display...

heres the NEW link to my main: http://pastebin.com/gasu1Hux

i have been looking up GLm tutorials but i cant find any correct answers about my texture not displaying at all.....

maybe im missing something?

/////////////////////OLD/////////////////////////////

also i tried the one from devernay.free.fr, but i always get a texture error
(not gonna post because everytime i do, my question gets downed...)

i had gotten a small glitch where my whole model is blue instead of the default gray...

i found out that the GLM library i have doesnt load textures by itself..

so i managed to find a texture loader from 3dcodingtutorial.com

when i load the texture its not put on the model, it just changes its color.

right now im wondering why my model is one single color instead of the texture i setup.

heres some of the code that i used to make the texture and draw the model:

ok heres the main.cpp

sorry wrong paste ._.

the paste has been updated!!

http://pastebin.com/tcwwasb9

Comment: Capitalization, linkification, etc.  Also it's generally not very useful to post a small snippet of code that references undefined classes/structures, doubly so when you're asking about GL state that those classes/structures might be modifying :)

Comment: OK GIVE ME A SEC ILL LOAD UP THE FILE oops caps xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default [`GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml) is `GL_MODULATE`.  Make sure you aren't inadvertently setting your color state somewhere, or force the issue with `glColor3ub(255,255,255)` before you render something with a texture.

EDIT: `GL_DECAL` is also an option.

Comment: uhh...i dont totally get what you said...i think ims stupid if its simple

Comment: `GL_MODULATE` will multiply texture RGB triplets with the current color RGB triplet.  Thus, if you set the color to RGB(255,0,0) your texture would end up rendering as if you knocked out the green and blue channels (i.e., all reddish).  There are a number of GL operations that change the current color as a side-effect.   See the [spec](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/).

Comment: i dont think its a color thing, because the entire model is one color, but shaded. wouldnt it have different levels of that color if it were a GL_MODULATE problem? also i still dont get it :(...ima try searching these up unless u dont mind helpin me out. would i be using glTexEnv by chance?

Comment: yeah i think the one color thing is resulting from my lighting, but why would it do that now since i already had the model lit(it was grey before i put the texture). thats very odd..also im thinking that im just missing something. but i cant remember what that is..

Comment: Does `WorldMap3Dv1.obj` contain `vt` texture coordinate directives?

Comment: yes it does, it has many of them xD could the order of the coords(v vt so on) matter?

Comment: well i changed how the texture is being loaded and instead of the world being blue, its grey again(with some lighting of course) so i think im going in the right direction. ill update on what i did